# Using the divergence theorem to calculate the surface integral of a sphere

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Hi so I have the question to use the divergence theorem to calculate the surface integral of the sphere

> Let $S=\{(x,y,z):(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 + (z-c)^2 = R^2\}$ and $f = (x^2,y^2,z^2)$. Evaluate
>   $$I=\iint_S fdS.$$

By the divergence theorem, I get that
$$I=\iiint_B \text{div}(f)dV$$
where $B=\{(x,y,z):(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 + (z-c)^2 \leq R^2\}$.

I get $\text{div}(f) = 2x+2y+2z$, I’m just wondering where to go from here, are the $(x-a)^2$ and $0$ the boundaries for my triple integral?

Answer (score 2):

We have to evaluate
$$\iiint_{(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 + (z-c)^2 \leq R^2} (2x+2y+2z)dxdydz$$
which is equal to
$$2\iiint_{X^2 + Y^2 + Z^2 \leq R^2} ((a+X)+(b+Y)+(c+Z))dXdYdZ$$
where $X=x-a$, $Y=y-b$, $Z=z-c$. 
 Since the ball $X^2 + Y^2 + Z^2 \leq R^2$ is symmetric with respect to the plane $X=0$, it follows that the integral of $X$ over the ball is zero. The same for $Y$ and $Z$.  Therefore, we finally obtain 
$$2(a+b+c)\cdot \frac{4\pi R^2}{3}.$$

Comment: When you say ‘By symmetry’ what do you mean?

Comment: I mean that since the ball is symmetric with respct to the plane $X=0$ the integral of $ X $ over the ball is zero. The same for $Y$ and $Z$.

Answer (score 0):

For the parametrization you can use the "shifted" spherical coordinates. Let:

$$x = r\cos \theta \sin \phi + a$$
$$y = r \sin \theta \sin \phi + b$$
$$z = r \cos \phi + c$$

Now it's not hard to get that $0 \le r \le R$, $0 \le \theta \le 2\pi$, $0 \le \phi \le \pi$. Now you can evaluate the integral on your own, which shouldn't be hard.

Comment: Thanks for the comment mate I appreciate it

Comment: @user505135 You're welcome. Hopefully it was helpful to you.